# Why does my shell script give me this error?

Tags: shell

I have a shell script, that should move the most recently downloaded file to the current folder

```
#!/bin/zsh

lastfile=$(ls -t ~/Downloads | head -n 1)
mv "~/Downloads/${lastfile}" .
```

However, say the most recently dowloaded file in the `Downloads` folder is called `test.png` then running the script gives me the error

`mv: rename ~/Downloads/test.png to ./test.png: No such file or directory`

Anyone know why that is happening?

Comment: Quoting `~` prevents it from being expanded. Use `~/Downloads/"$lastfile"`.

Comment: you might add the following to help debug, before the `mv`, e.g., `ls -l ~/Downloads/"${lastfile}"`, and also modify the `mv` to check that it's a file (both exists & is not a directory): `[ -f ~/Downloads/"${lastfile}" ] && mv ~/Downloads/"${lastfile}" .` (that's basically "if test -f file then mv file") *edit:* yeah, don't quote the `~`

Comment: `~` is not a directory name; it's a shell shortcut that needs to be expanded to a directory name. You can always replace `~` with `$HOME`. Use tilde expansion at the command line where you want to type as few characters as possible; use `$HOME` in a script where readability is more important.

Comment: Since you are in zsh, it's easiest to drop the quotes and just write `my ~/Downloads/$lastfile .`

Comment: `zsh` also lets you write `mv ~/Downloads/*(om[1]) .` without worrying about the output of `ls`. (The `om` sorts by modification like `ls -t`, the `[1]` selects the first match.)

Answer (score -1):

When using the mv command you can just specify the folder to which you wish to move the file to:

```
#!/bin/zsh

lastfile=$(ls -t ~/Downloads | head -n 1)
mv "~/Downloads/${lastfile}" .
```

Comment: This is the exact code the OP already has.